# How to remove menu items?

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, configuration, menu

I want to remove these items from the *System* menu:

- Help and Support
- About Gnome
- About Ubuntu

I can't do this with *Main Menu* (bad naming, should be menumanager or so).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to simply rename three files.
Run these commands in a terminal:

```
cd /usr/share/applications
sudo mv gnome-about.desktop gnome-about.desktop.bak 
sudo mv ubuntu-about.desktop ubuntu-about.desktop.bak
sudo mv yelp.desktop yelp.desktop.bak
```

To add them back to the *System* menu:

```
cd /usr/share/applications
sudo mv gnome-about.desktop.bak gnome-about.desktop 
sudo mv ubuntu-about.desktop.bak ubuntu-about.desktop
sudo mv yelp.desktop.bak yelp.desktop
```

I was looking at the `gnome-panel` source code and it seems these three items are hardcoded to be included in the *System* Menu, but if the applet can't find those `.desktop` files with those exact names they won't be added.

Here is what the *System* menu looks like after renaming those files:

[image]

Comment: Is is easy or difficult to insert menu items there?

Comment: @LeonardoMontenegro In the system menu? No it is not hard, but I can't explain it very well in a comment. You should ask that as a separate question. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `sudo apt-get purge yelp`, it will remove Help and Support.

Comment: there is also a way to remove them from from the menu by deleting some files, while keeping the help program (if I remember I will post it).